# Infinte Scroll Only Works After Refresh?

Tags: html, post, themes, tumblr

For some reason the images stack on top of each other when I use infinite scroll. However if I refresh the page they are displayed correctly?

Here is an example of the issue on the initial load:

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img19/8550/kibu.png]

Here is the html code: 
[www.pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JRU4X1CQ](http://www.pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JRU4X1CQ)

And this is my tumblr with this theme: [www.trollophotography.tumblr.com](http://www.trollophotography.tumblr.com)

How can i fix this?